# Use double quotes when setting a variable

Tags: variables, plsql

I have a PL/SQL script where I am trying to populate a CLOB which contains XML data.

```
DECLARE
  bigtext1   VARCHAR2 (32767);
BEGIN

  bigtext1 :='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';

  UPDATE SCREEN SET XML=bigtext1
  WHERE SCREEN_REF='TEST';
END;
```

This is just an example, in my real use of this the bigtext1 field is considerably bigger. My issue is that I can't figure out how to have double quote in the setting of the bigtext1 variable. I keep getting this error:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol " " when expecting one of the
>   following:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double quotes are not your problem. 
See the SQLFiddle example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/054bc/1

My guess is that you have some other single quote inside your XML and that is causing the problem.

To overcome that, you could use the alternate quote mechanisme (details [in the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements003.htm#i42617)). You just need to find some character that is definitely not part of your XML. Assuzming that is e.g. `§`, you can writer your code like this:

```
DECLARE
  bigtext1   VARCHAR2 (32767);
BEGIN

  bigtext1 := q'§<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>§';

  UPDATE SCREEN SET XML=bigtext1
  WHERE SCREEN_REF='TEST';
END;
/
```

I usually also put the opening and closing delimiters on their own lines to make reading the code easier:

```
DECLARE
  bigtext1   VARCHAR2 (32767);
BEGIN

  bigtext1 := 
  q'§
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <foo id='bar' code="hello">Hello, World</foo>
  §';

  UPDATE SCREEN SET XML=bigtext1
  WHERE SCREEN_REF='TEST';
END;
/
```

Note the embedded single and double quotes inside the XML without the need to mask them in any way. See the modified SQLFiddle example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/054bc/7

Answer (score 0):

As @a_horse_with_no_name stated:

> The double quotes are not your problem.

You misread the error message:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol " " when expecting one of the following:
```

It's not saying that the double quote(s) is the unexpected symbol - the quotes are part of the error message. The symbol it is complaining about is inside the quotes. In this case the symbol renders as a whitespace so I bet for end of line (crlf vs. lf) or file encoding issue.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you should try escaping them?

```
bigtext1 :='<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>';
```

Comment: Double quotes have no special meaning inside a string literal with single quotes. And SQL (including PL/SQL) does not have any escaping syntax like that.